# Is rails 4 find_by deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I heard that find_by is deprecated is this true? I have been thinking of alternatives such as creating for each `find` a different method, e.g.:

before:

```
Model.find_by_username 'username'
```

after:
--in model---

```
class << self
   def by_username username
      where(:username => username).first 
   end
end
```

is it a good naming? what names do you give for such methods?

### Update:

[find_by is not deprecated but the announcement could have been clearer!](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations)

Comment: Where did you get the information that `find_by_...` is deprecated?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the [Rails 4 Release Notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations):

> All *dynamic* methods except for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated.

`find_by` is not a dynamic method and therefore **it's NOT DEPRECATED**, and `find_by_...` & `find_by_...!` are dynamic, but still not deprecated as mentioned above.

So that means you still can use the original methods provided by Active Record without having to define your own:

```
Model.find_by_username(:username)
Model.find_by(username: 'value', age: 24)
```

If you want the functionality of the really deprecated finder methods you can either include the gem that they were moved into: [activerecord-deprecated_finders](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders). Or follow what the Rails 4 Release Notes say:

> Here's how you can rewrite the code:
>
> - find_all_by_... can be rewritten using where(...).
> - find_last_by_... can be rewritten using where(...).last.
> - scoped_by_... can be rewritten using where(...).
> - find_or_initialize_by_... can be rewritten using find_or_initialize_by(...).
> - find_or_create_by_... can be rewritten using find_or_create_by(...).
> - find_or_create_by_...! can be rewritten using find_or_create_by!(...).

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid cluttering your model with such methods. Also, Rails still provides the `find_by` method. Thus I think a better solution would be

```
Model.find_by(username: 'whatever_username')
```

Comment: @TamerShlash No it isn't. Please read the [release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations)

Answer (score -3):

It was deprecated in favour of

```
Model.find_by username: 'username'
```

so you should probably use this version.

Comment: @Iceman No it isn't. Please read the [release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations)

Comment: @Iceman no it isn't. `find_by_*` are deprecated not `find_by`. `find_by_*` methods was moved into `deprecated-finders` gem and `find_by` is still absolutely ok.

Comment: @Iceman check the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-by) as further evidence that `find_by` was not depreciated.

Comment: @JKen13579 While it's true that `find_by` is not deprecated. The rails guide still includes documentation for some deprecated methods like mentioned [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-build-a-new-object).

Comment: @TamerShlash very good point. Although anything that's deprecated is marked with that yellow background warning.