# undefined method `find_all_by_X'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.0, ruby-2.1

Currently maintaining some old Ruby server and got the following error in Log:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `find_all_by_X_ID' for #<Class:0x00000005555555>):
  app/controllers/some_controller.rb:10:in `buggy_function'
```

When viewed the faulty line in code of the buggy function is looks like this:

```
Hash[S.find_all_by_X_ID(TaskRun.select(:x_id).uniq.where(y_id: @y.Y_ID).map(&:x_id)).map { |s| [s.S_IDENTIFIER, s.X_ID] }]
```

To be frank, I'm new to Ruby, and wondering how implementing this `find_all_by_X` query would be the best, and why it appears as it should be automatic (as it has to do with the model component).

We're working on Ruby version 2.

Comment: Why Ruby 2.0? That's woefully obsolete and risky to use. You should be on 2.5 or 2.6. There's some issues with >2.4 if you're using a really old code-base, but for anything new it should be fine.

Comment: Defiantly Ruby 2 is not the best option, yet to update the system @tadman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `find_all_by` was deprecated in Rails 4 ...

Internally Rails implemented methods like `find_all_by_x_id` using [method_missing](https://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/method_missing) (the method is actually defined dynamically through metaprogramming) ... but you don't have to worry about that for your use-case.

In terms of your code, if we extract the x_ids list into a variable:

```
x_ids = TaskRun.select(:x_id).uniq.where(y_id: @y.Y_ID).map(&:x_id)
```

Then you have this line that you need to rewrite:

```
S.find_all_by_X_ID(x_ids)
```

You can rewrite this as:

```
S.where(x_id: x_ids)
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23921890/2981429

Comment: `where` is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you @max-pleaner
Any idea why this would occur (although not working with Ruby 4, and in Ruby 2 should not be deprecated)?

Comment: `TaskRun.select(:x_id).uniq.where(y_id: @y.Y_ID).map(&:x_id)` while this line may work; if there are a significant number of x_ids then you can run into query length issues not to mention performance issues. One would be better off with `x_ids = TaskRun.select(:x_id).where(y_id: @y.Y_ID).distinct` this will return an ActiveRecord::Relation and when used later `S.where(x_id: x_ids)` will result in a subquery rather than a very large IN statement

Comment: Thank you much! @engineersmnky

Comment: I didn't realize that either @engineersmnky interesting info, thanks

Comment: maxpleaner @engineersmnky Does any of you have an idea why this 'find_all_by_X_ID' would not be found? although working in Ruby 2 where it should be recognized

Comment: @SharonCohen it has nothing to do with your ruby version, it's the rails version that matters rails 4 deprecated `find_all_by_...` and rails 5 removed them entirely so if you are using rails 5 that method will not exist and should be replaced by `where` [Rails 4 depreciations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations)